# Infinite zeros in infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, fourier-series, infinity

**The problem:**

> Given that
>
> $$\frac{\pi}{4} = 1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{9} + \ldots $$
>
> Prove
>
> $$\frac{\pi}{3} = 1 + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} - \frac{1}{11} + \frac{1}{13} + \frac{1}{17} + \ldots$$

**My solution:**

We know

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\pi}{4} & = 1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{9} -\frac{1}{11} + \frac{1}{13} - \frac{1}{15} + \ldots \\
\\
\frac{\pi}{12} & = \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{15} - \frac{1}{21} + \frac{1}{27} -\frac{1}{33} + \frac{1}{39} - \frac{1}{45} + \ldots\\
\\
& = 0 + \frac{1}{3} + 0 + 0 - \frac{1}{9} + 0 + 0 + \frac{1}{15} + 0 + 0 - \frac{1}{21}
\end{align}
$$

now add them together:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{\pi}{12} & = 1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{9} - \frac{1}{11} + \frac{1}{13} - \frac{1}{15} + \ldots \\
\\
& + 0 + \frac{1}{3} + 0 + 0 - \frac{1}{9} + 0 + 0 + \frac{1}{15} + \ldots \\
\end{align}
$$

and we will get:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\pi}{3} & = 1 + 0 + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + 0 -\frac{1}{11} + \frac{1}{13} + 0 + \ldots \\
& =  1 + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} -\frac{1}{11} + \frac{1}{13} + \ldots
\end{align}
$$

**My questions:**

- I inserted/removed *infinite* zeros into/from the series, is that OK?
- My solution relies on the fact that $\Sigma a_n + \Sigma b_n = \Sigma (a_n + b_n)$ and $k \Sigma a_n = \Sigma k a_n$. Is this always true for convergent infinite series? If so, why is it? (yeah I know this is a stupid question, but since I'm adding infinite terms up, I'd better pay some attention.)
- Bouns question: Can I *arbitrarily* (arbitrariness isn't infinity, you know) insert/remove zeros into/from a convergent infinite series, without changing its convergence value?

Comment: My apologies.  Inserting zeros is definitely not the same as rearranging.  Inserting zeros in the series as you have done will not change the value of the series.

Comment: @sharding4 Thanks. This is quite intuitive :) But can we _rigidly_ prove this statement, say, with epsilon-delta definition?

Comment: You could probably approach the sequence of partial sums as a Cauchy sequence.  Then adding a finite, fixed number of zeros at fixed intervals is the same as inserting duplicate terms into a Cauchy sequence.  You may need to adjust for the slower convergence, but the sequence will still be Cauchy.

Comment: Your series result can also be viewed in terms of Dirichlet $L$ series and Euler Products.  Leibniz' series for $\pi/4$ is also a familiar Dirichlet series evaluated at 1.  This series also has the product representation $\prod_p (1-\chi(p)/p)^{-1}$ where $\chi(p)= \pm 1\equiv p\bmod 4$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  Note multiplying the series for $\pi/4$ by $4/3$ would be very different.  His series has eliminated all the multiples of 3.  It's the same as what you would get by eliminating the factor containing 3 from the Euler Product for the L-series with character modulo 4.

Comment: @sharding4: all right, but such elimination is not requested by the main problem. That is the reason for me asking the actual meaning of *calculate*. Otherwise, we may just ignore Gregory's series and write $\frac{\pi}{3}$ as $2\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$, then compute the Taylor series of $\arcsin(x)$, for instance.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio My apologies. The question should be "Given that π/4=..., prove π/3=...". The given series that coverage to `π/4` actually comes from the Fourier series of `f(x)=-π/4, -π<x<0; π/4, 0<x<π`. This question is a part of a bigger question, and I made a mistake when dividing the it into small pieces. Going to edit the question to clarify...

Comment: I assume you mean something like "Prove $\displaystyle \frac\pi3 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \left( \frac1{6k+1} + \frac1{6k+5} \right)$"? Because, at least to me, it's far from obvious at a glance how to continue the series based on just the first 6 terms.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Yes, this is what I mean! However, at least to me, $\frac{\pi}{3} = 1 + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} - \frac{1}{11} + \frac{1}{13} + \frac{1}{17} + \ldots$ seems more clear. Please feel free to edit my post, though.

Comment: Another way to solve it  is that $\pi /4+d_n=\sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^n/(2j-1)$ and $\pi /12+e_n=\sum_{0\leq j\leq (2n-1)/3}(-1)^n/3(2j-1))$ where $d_n\to 0 $ and $e_n\to 0$  as $n\to \infty$. Subtracting,  $\pi /4 +(d_n-e_n)$ is the sum of all of the terms of the third series that have denominators less than or equal to $2n-1.$

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Yes, that is ok.
2. Yes it is. The partial sum of $\sum_k (a_k+b_k)$ is the partial sum of $\sum_ka_k$ plus the partial sum of $\sum_k b_k.$ The result follows from the sum property for limits.
3. Yes. Adding zeros will only delay the inevitable convergence of the sequence of partial sums. Where you insert zeros, the sequence of partial sums will hold flat. For the $N$ you find in the proof of convergence of the original, simply replace with $N$ plus the number of zeros you inserted before the N-th and you'll have the same value that will be within $\epsilon$ of the number the sum converges to.

Answer (score 9):

Both the given identities follow from the fact that $\frac{\pi}{\text{something}}$ is related with the integral over $(0,1)$ of a rational function. The first identity is a consequence of 
$$\frac{\pi}{4} = \arctan(1)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \int_{0}^{1}\left(1-x^2+x^4-x^6+\ldots\right)\,dx $$
and for the second series we may perform the same manipulation in the opposite direction, leading to:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{1}{12n+1}+\frac{1}{12n+5}-\frac{1}{12n+7}-\frac{1}{12n+11}\right)&=&\int_{0}^{1}(1+x^4-x^6-x^{10})\sum_{n\geq 0}x^{12n}\,dx\\&=&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1+x^4}{1+x^6}\,dx\\&=&\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{x^2}{1+x^6}\right)\,dx\\(x\mapsto z^{1/3})\qquad &=&\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dz}{1+z^2}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{3}}.\end{eqnarray*} $$

Indeed, we are just multipling the first series by $\frac{4}{3}$ :D

Comment: Is it really correct to try to integrate termwise a series which diverges at one of the limits (despite convergence for all other points of the domain of integration)?

Comment: @Ruslan: in the shown manipulation, we never deal with a divergent series. $\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{1}{12n+1}+\ldots\right)$ is an absolutely convergent series and $\frac{1+x^4}{1+x^6}$ is a continuous and bounded function over $[0,1]$, so there is no issue.

Comment: I mean the first of the displayed equations, its rightmost side. The integrand diverges at $x=1$.

Comment: About the arctangent, $\sum_{n=1}(-1)^n x^{2n}$ is not really *divergent* at $x=1$, since its partial sums are still bounded. Since the point $x=1$ has measure zero, we are allowed to perform the shown manipulation: if some $f(x)$ is continuous and bounded over $[0,1]$ and it is not really defined at $x=0$ or $x=1$, we may simply ignore the issue since $\int_{[0,1]}f(x)\,dx = \int_{(0,1)}f(x)\,dx$.

Answer (score 3):

It is a rewarding  exercise to write, or read,  detailed rigorous proofs of  some simple, "obvious" results.

The definition of $x=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}y_j$ is that $x=\lim_{n\to \infty}S_n$ where $S_n=\sum_{j=1}^ny_j.$   A useful  way to state (or define) that the sequence $S=(S_n)_n$ converges to $x$  is that for any $r>0 $ the set $$F(S, r)=\{n: S_n\not \in [-r+x,r+x]\}$$ is a finite set.

Let  $x=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}y_j.$  Insert some $0$'s into the sequence $(y_j)_j$ to produce a new sequence $(z_i)_i.$ For each $i$ we have either $z_i=0$ or $z_i=y_{g(i)}$ where $g(i)\leq i.$

Let $T=(T_m)_m$ where $T_m=\sum_{i=1}^mz_i.$

Let $i_0$ be the least (or any) $i$ such that $z_i=y_1.$

Then for every $m\geq i_0$ we have $T_m=\sum_{  \{g(i):i\leq m\}}y_{g(i)}= S_{f(m)}$  where $f(m)=\max \{g(i):i\leq m\}.$

Note that for any $n$ there exists $m_0$ such that $z_{m_0}=y_{n+1}$ so there exists $m_0$ such that $f(m_0)=n+1.$

Now for any $r>0$ we have  $$F(T,r)=\{m:T_m\not \in [-r+x,r+x]\}\subset \{m\geq i_0:S_{f(m)} \not \in [-r+x.r+x]\}\cup \{m:m<i_0\}$$ $$=\{m\geq i_0: f(m)\in F(S,r)\}\cup \{m:m<i_0\}.$$  Observe that for any $n$ the set $\{m\geq i_0: f(m)=n\}$ is a finite set, because there exists $m_0$ such that $f(m_0)=n+1,$ and hence $m\geq m_0\implies f(m)>n.$ And recall that $F(S,r)$ is a  finite set because the sequence $S$ converges to $x.$

So for any $r>0$ the set $F(T,r)$ is a subset of a union of a finite collection of finite sets: $$F(T,r)\subset (\cup_{n\in F(S,r)}\{m\geq  i_0:f(m)=n\})\cup \{m:m<i_0\}.$$ Therefore $F(T,r)$ is finite for every $r>0$. Therefore $T$ converges to $x.$ Therefore $x=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}z_i.$

Comment: Some "obvious" results turn out to require long and  difficult  proofs. For example the Jordan Curve  Theorem.